# how to add a classList in react using material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to add a class to an element using Material UI in a scroll event like this.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
 
  sticky: {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    width: '100%',
  }

});


export default function myBar() {

 React.useEffect(() => {
    const myBar = document.getElementById("myBar");
    const sticky = myBar.offsetTop;
   
    const scrolling = window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
          myBar.classList.add("sticky");
        } else {
          myBar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
        
      });
      
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrolling);
      };
    
    }, []);



  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <header id="myBar">
      // some content
    </header>
  );
};
```

The problem is that Mterial Ui will generate some random numbers after class name, like `sticky_123` so it will never be only `sticky`

Is it any way I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that Material Ui will generate some random numbers after class name, like sticky_123 so it will never be only sticky

In order to use the className generated by Material UI, you must use `classes.sticky` instead of `"sticky"`.

By the way, the component name should be in PascalCase.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  sticky: {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    width: '100%',
  }
});

export default function MyBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  useEffect(() => {
    const myBar = document.getElementById("myBar");
    const sticky = myBar.offsetTop;
   
    const scrollHandler = () => {
      if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        myBar.classList.add(classes.sticky);
      } else {
        myBar.classList.remove(classes.sticky);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler)
      
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
    };
  }, [classes]);

  return (
    <header id="myBar">
      // some content
    </header>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it.